# Trouble Calling a Loop in my Thread

Tags: java, android, loops

I seem to be having some troubles calling the loop within my game thread, but I'm not sure what the issue may be. I call it just fine and I'm not sure why it wont call the loop. Here is an annotated chunk of code:

```
public class GameThread<MainGamePanel> extends Thread 
{
    private static final String TAG = GameThread.class.getSimpleName();

    private GameView myGameView;

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private MainGamePanel gamePanel;
    private boolean running;
    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
        System.out.println("tag: setRunning"); //successful
    }

    public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel)
    {
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
        System.out.println("tag: GameThread"); //successful
    }

    public void run(Activity activity) 
    {
        System.out.println("tag: run"); //failed
        myGameView = new GameView(activity);
        this.myGameView = new GameView(activity);
        Canvas canvas;
        long tickCount = 0L;
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
        while (running) {
            tickCount++;
            canvas = null;
            // update game state
            myGameView.onUpdate();

            // render state to the screen
            try 
            {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) 
                {
                    // update game state 
                    // draws the canvas on the panel
                    if (canvas != null)
                        ((GameView) this.gamePanel).onDraw(canvas);             
                }
            } 
            finally 
            {
                // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
                // an inconsistent state
                if (canvas != null)
                {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }   // end finally
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Game loop executed " + tickCount + " times");
    }
}
```

You can see where my prints have failed.

and here is an annotated version of the view that calls it:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public static GameView myGameView;

    static int screenWidth;
    static int screenHeight;

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        System.out.println("tag: onDraw"); //failed
    }

    public void onUpdate()
    {
        System.out.println("tag: onUpdate"); //failed
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        return true;
    }


    private GameThread thread;
    public GameView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        // Get Screen Dimensions
        screenWidth = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        screenHeight = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);


        // make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
        setFocusable(true);
        System.out.println("tag: GameView"); //Successful
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) 
    {

    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
        System.out.println("tag: surfaceCreated"); //successful
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry)
        {
            try
            {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // try again shutting down the thread
            }
        }
        System.out.println("tag: SurfaceDestroyed"); //Successful
    }
}
```

both failed methods in the latter are what should be called within the loop in the thread. I have attempted to call my thread via "thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);" but I'm not sure why that wont work.

I also have [This](http://pastie.org/pastes/8956547/text) as the setup class that launches everything, but this seems to work just fine as the view *is* called, it just doesn't seem to run as it should within itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try adding @Override to your run() method. Ex)

`@Override`


public void run(Activity activity) `

Comment: My guess, second thread is using cached `running` value. Try make it volatile.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the code here:

```
    myGameView = new GameView(activity);
    this.myGameView = new GameView(activity);
    Canvas canvas;
    long tickCount = 0L;
```

To the constructor as it's a part of GameThread and not `Thread`. It's also preferred to use `Implements Runnable` over `Extends Thread` as it allows a clear separation between the Thread's behavior and the actual Thread being called and executed.

But for your specific problem, you're extending Thread which already has a run() method, which is being called at `thread.start()` which is by default empty, so your implementation of run(Activity activity) is never being called. If you want to override the super class's method, you need to specify that with @Override:

```
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        //etc etc
    }
```

To elaborate along switching to `implements Runnable`:

```
public class GameThread<MainGamePanel> Implements Runnable  
{
    private static final String TAG = GameThread.class.getSimpleName();

    private GameView myGameView;

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private MainGamePanel gamePanel;
    private boolean running;

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
        System.out.println("tag: setRunning"); //successful
    }

    public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel, Activity activity)
    {
        super();
        //myGameView = new GameView(activity); <-- redundant
        this.myGameView = new GameView(activity);
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
        System.out.println("tag: GameThread"); //successful
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("tag: run"); 
        Canvas canvas = null;
        long tickCount = 0L;
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
        while (running) {
            tickCount++;
            // update game state
            myGameView.onUpdate();

            // render state to the screen
            try 
            {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) 
                {
                    // update game state 
                    // draws the canvas on the panel
                    if (canvas != null)
                        ((GameView) this.gamePanel).onDraw(canvas);             
                }
            } 
            finally 
            {
                // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
                // an inconsistent state
                if (canvas != null)
                {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }   // end finally
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Game loop executed " + tickCount + " times");
    }
}
```

And change your calling method to:

```
Runnable gameThread = new GameThread(params); 

new Thread(gameThread).start(); //(.start() will begin your run() method in the thread)
```

(Couldn't tell where you were passing your Activity, but you'll need to account for that as well.)

Comment: hm, but on doing this, I am getting an issue with the Activity I am trying to pass on to the run function - "The method run(Activity) of type GameThread<MainGamePanel> must override or implement a supertype method"

Comment: Meant to also move the Activity param to the constructor as well, like I did with the code setting it. Updated.